# Converting Pandas Datetime to Postgres Date

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I am working with Pandas to add a field that is a string to a date and add another field that would be the date of yesterday.

I am using `pytz` to set the timezone on the `stat_date` field, but I am still getting an error on the `to_sql` commmand.

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')

df.insert(1, 'feed_date', pd.to_datetime(df['feed_id'],  errors='coerce'))
df.insert(1, 'stat_date', pd.to_datetime(datetime.now(tz).date()) - timedelta(days=1))

df.to_sql("table", engine, if_exists='append', index=False, schema="stats")
```

Error:

```
DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat) invalid input syntax for type date
```

What is the proper way to convert datetime from pandas to postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `format='%Y-%m-%d'` to `df.insert`

```
df.insert(1, 'feed_date',format='%Y-%m-%d' ,pd.to_datetime(df['feed_id'],  
errors='coerce'))
df.insert(1, 'stat_date', format='%Y-%m- 
%d',pd.to_datetime(datetime.now(tz).date()) - timedelta(days=1))
```